# Hardware compatibility issue

Tags: hardware, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I am using a custom-built PC with an AMD FX 8350 CPU and an ASUS M5A78LM USB 3 motherboard and a AMD Radeon R9 280X graphics Card.

I am currently using Windows 10 and i want to install Ubuntu alongside it with dual boot.

I just wanted to know if my hardware is completely supported and safely runs Ubuntu and it wont damage my hardware. Also i would like to know if anyone with my hardware has successfully run Ubuntu without any issues.

Comment: Best to boot a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in `Try Ubuntu` mode and see if/how it works with your hardware.

Comment: Your graphics card is Linux-compatible according to https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=R9+280X&typeid=graphics+card.